# Spring, java - different constructor args - best practice pattern

Tags: java, spring, constructor-injection

Have the following structure in a spring rest mvc service app.

- If controller A is called, 2 constructor arguments should be used to create Service B.
- If controller B is called, 2 different constructor values should be used to create Service B.
- Service A is injected into Controller A and Service B is injected in Service A.

Controller A -> Service A -> Service B (String param_url_1, RestTemplate param_template_1)

Controller B -> Service A -> Service B (String param_url_2, RestTemplate param_template_2)

Is there a recommended pattern to handle this?

Sample code:

```
@RequstMapping("v1/api")
public class ControllerA {

  ServiceA serviceA;

  ControlllerA(ServiceA serviceA){
     this.serviceA = serviceA
  }

  @GetMapping("/doSomething")
  public void doSomething{
    serviceA.doSomething();
  }
}

@RequstMapping("v2/api")
public class ControllerB {

   ServiceA serviceA;

   ControlllerB(ServiceA serviceA){
     this.serviceA = serviceA
   }

   @GetMapping("/doSomethingDifferent")
   public void doSomething{
     serviceA.doSomething();
   }
}


public class ServiceA {

   ServiceB serviceB;

   ServiceA(ServiceB serviceB){
     this.serviceB = serviceB
   }

   public void doSomething{{
    serviceB.serviceBMethod();
   }
}

public class ServiceB {

  ServiceB(String url,
         RestTemplate template){
     this.url = url;
     this.template = template;
   }

   public void serviceBMethod{{
    template.invoke(url);
   }
 }
```

In the above example url and template would have different values depending on which controller started the invocation.

Comment: Please be more specific in your example. It is usual for services to be created once, not for different calls. You _might_ be looking for `@Qualifier` used with `@Bean` methods.

Comment: I just stumbled on the @Qualifier in this link:https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers

Attempted to implement, however there are a couple of different classes that extend OAuth2RestTemplate that I'm trying to use. I put OAuth2RestTemplate as a field within the qualifier and got and "invalid type for annotation member" error. Is there something in particular you would like me to be more specific about? Basically if controller a is invoked there's a different string value and restemplate I would like inject

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Builder Design Pattern for this. In this case, you can add parameters in a fluent way for complex constructors that contain a large number of parameters.

to deal with the different interfaces you have, you can use the Adpater Design Pattern: https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/adapter

you can read more about the Builder here: https://dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-the-builder-pattern

Comment: I don't see how the builder or adapter pattern addresses the question. I think the qualifier mentioned by chrylis is headed down the right path.